# Cómo subir un proyecto realizado con Codeigniter 3 a un hosting?

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, codeigniter-3, cpanel

He intentado de varias maneras y no me resulta, soy nuevo en codeigniter así que por favor no me maten...
Me aparece el siguiente mensaje...

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

Dejo aquí los archivos de configuración...

```
// config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.midominio.cl/eltit_remu/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

// $routes.php
$route['default_controller'] = 'cilogin'; // Controlador por defecto...

// cilogin.php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CiLogin extends CI_Controller {
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('login'); // Cargamos los modelos
        $this->load->model('usuarios'); 
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }

...

// .htaccess
Rewriteengine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

También quisiera mencionar que al mismo hosting ya subí un proyecto y me funciona bien, la diferencia es que este no tiene el archivo .htacess...

Comment: intenta poner `https://www.midominio.cl/index.php/eltit_remu/`

Comment: depende del sistema de archivos de tu host, prueba cambiar el nombre del archivo a **CiLogin.php**

Comment: @valle50 me muestra un mensaje que dice " File not found. "

Comment: @AbrahamChan no me funciona tampoco :(

Comment: por lo que veo estás utilizando un subdirectorio para tu app https://www.midominio.cl/eltit_remu/ lo digo por `/eltit_remo`

Comment: @RafaelBautista si amigazo, en ese caso al .htaccess se le debe agregar antes del index.php la referencia a esa carpeta? por ej eltit_remu/index.php/$1 ?

Comment: @Victor y si en el .htaccess agregas : `RewriteBase /eltit_remu` justo abajo de `Rewriteengine On` ?

Comment: Por cierto es `RewriteEngine` con la E mayúscula

Comment: @RafaelBautista tampoco me funciona, y ya corregí la E mayúscula. Es raro porque como mencioné al final de la pregunta ya subí un proyecto completo el cual puedo acceder con "midominio.cl/apptrack/", ahora quiero hacer lo mismo sólo que con htaccess para que la ruta sea más amigable